# PHP FreeType support not working inside GD

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile PHP 5.2 as I need to run an older application on a new server.  I'm using this configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --enable-soap --with-pear --with-pgsql --with-curl=/usr/bin --enable-bcmath --enable-ftp --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-pgsql --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds --with-ttf=/usr/lib --with-t1lib --with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 --with-gd --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --with-mm
```

There are no errors when I run that configure, however, some of the log messages show that it sees FreeType...?

```
checking for GD support... yes
checking for the location of libjpeg... no
checking for the location of libpng... no
checking for the location of libXpm... /usr/lib
checking for FreeType 1.x support... /usr/lib
checking for FreeType 2... /usr/include/freetype2
checking for T1lib support... yes
checking whether to enable truetype string function in GD... no
checking whether to enable JIS-mapped Japanese font support in GD... no
checking for fabsf... (cached) yes
checking for floorf... (cached) yes
If configure fails try --with-jpeg-dir=<DIR>
checking for png_write_image in -lpng... (cached) yes
checking for XpmFreeXpmImage in -lXpm... (cached) yes
checking for FT_New_Face in -lfreetype... (cached) yes
checking for FreeType 1 support... no - FreeType 2.x is to be used instead
checking for T1_StrError in -lt1... (cached) yes
```

Even with all of that specified, I still just get

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

The old server this application is coming from has this in the GD section of the phpinfo:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.5
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

The new server is an Ubuntu 13.04 Server and I have `libfreetype6` installed.  What am I doing wrong that FreeType is not showing up as enabled?

Comment: Does freetype exist at `/usr/include/freetype2`? Is the directory readable?

Comment: It does.  freetype.a and freetype.so are in /usr/lib/i386-linux however.  So, I have also tried doing `--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/i386-linux` which yields the same results.

Comment: The directory is also readable.

Comment: Did you install FreeType manually or via a package manager? If the latter, which one?

Comment: I installed it through apt.  I did both `libfreetype6` and `libfreetype6-dev`.

Comment: apt does not appear to have built-in package verification like yum or rpm, so you might want to install debsums. Then you can do `sudo debsums -c libfreetype6` and `sudo debsums -c libfreetype6-dev` to verify the installation as recommended [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9463/what-is-the-apt-equivalent-to-rpm-v-verify-installed-packages).

Comment: I installed `debsums` and then did `apt-get install --reinstall libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev`.  Then I ran those commands.  Neither output anything.  Also, updated question with hopefully relevant configure log messages.

Comment: Okay, silly question: Have you verified that you are running from the newly-compiled version? Restarted apache, etc?

Comment: Yes.  That was the first thing I tried.  I compiled without specifying GD support and restarted Apache.  GD disappeared from the phpinfo.  So I know it's pulling from the correct one.

Comment: Are you doing `make clean` before each ./configure ? (Sorry for being pedantic, I just can't find anything more substantial at the moment).

Comment: *facepalm* Fixed all the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `make clean` ?